# How to change to directory when I click on link in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to run the `hello.php` from `input/index.php` to `input/output/hello.php` when the link on `index.php` was clicked. I have googled it but cannot find the solution? Any solution for this?

Comment: `output/hello.php` … and this has less to do with PHP, and rather more with how relative URLs work.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `/` in the URL.

```
<a href="output/hello.php">
```

Comment: this is work when your file is inside the output folder. @user3620243 you have to use .htaccess file if you jsut want to show output/ in the url Please follow this  
                                                                                                                        URL: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I- redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, i have a problem when just using (with your example) "output/hello.php" so i use "./output/hello.php", maybe it could work for you.

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking I think is more about URLs, you have to create a file called:

```
.htaccess
```

Just like that, with the dot at the beginning. You can use this code inside of it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php?u=$1
```

Now, all the requests are going to go to the index.php file, ALL!! no matter if you write /lalala, is still going to go to index.php, so you have to parse the URL, that way, you can know what are you receiving and be able to execute any method that you want.
Example:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
$parsedUrl['path'] // Is the var that has the info after yourdomain.com/
```

Once you have that, you can separate that with `explode('/', $parsedUrl['path'])` and analize the data.
So you can write /input/output/hello.php and you can receive the data in index.php